# How can i pass table tr first td attribute value to onclick of a function

Tags: jquery

I have this jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/dsda/1/

```
sdsadadsdsadsadsadasdasdsdsdsadsa
```

Comment: Don't do it inline.  Make a JQuery bind code block.

Comment: Because $(this) refers to the a element, you need to use .closest('tr') to select the tr element

Comment: you mean this way $(parent).('tr td:first').attr('myid')

Comment: If you insist on using `onclick=` then you should add the values the same way that you added them to the html in the first place (whatever server-side you are using to render the html).  You will end up with `onclick=check('32323', 'myurl')`.   The better option would be to use jquery to add the event handler, in which case you get `this` and can navigate quite easily.

Comment: No, try to do $(this).closest('tr').first().find('input').attr('myid');

Comment: Your problem is the jquery code `$(this).('tr td:first').attr('myid')` isn't valid, change to `$(this).closest('tr").find("td:first').attr('myid')`

Comment: Where is the question...?